# Integral-differential system of equations

Tags: calculus, integration, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

Let's have 2 real  continuous functions $X(z,t)$ and $Y(z,t)$ , defined for all real numbers.

It's known the equations system below :

$$\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{ \partial{X(z,t)}}{\partial{z}} dt = - \frac{Y(z,\tau)}{a} $$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Y(z,t) dz = b $$

$$\int _{0}^{\tau} \frac{\partial{Y(z,t)}}{\partial{z}} t dt = - X(z,\tau)\tau $$

, where $a$ , $b$ and $\tau$ are positive and known .

How can I find $\int_{0}^{\tau}Y(0,t)t dt $ ?

I'm new in this kind of equations. Any link with useful theory would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the function , I just know the equations above.